Gparted Operation and Support
Gparted forum was closed in March, so now there's nowhere to ask questions and get support.
Does this mean GParted is end of life?
The reason I am trying to get support is that the live USB method prompts the user to choose an option when booting from the USB, however all options, including safe, result in a static cursor on a black screen, and I have to do a hard reboot.
